# Plotting a Google defined "route"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the Google Places Autocomplete to return a "route" type, such as a street, I want to take that route and plot several markers along it on the map.

Example: Take the entire route of "Yonge Street, Toronto, ON, Canada" and place markers all along that street from the beginning to end.

Currently searching for "Yonge Street, Toronto, ON, Canada" returns a single Lat/Long point for the entire route.

This needs to be done in a way that doesn't involve me manually selecting each point as I need this to function for any Google "route" on the globe.

I am stumped as to way to do this using Google Maps API v3.. perhaps there is another service that can help me get the Lat/Long points I need which I can then feed to the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is currently not possible with the Google Maps API v3.  You could add an enhancement request to the [issues list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/), but doesn't seem likely to happen.

The [geocoder](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Yonge%20Street,%20Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada&geocode=1) actually returns 3 points along the road for your query ("Yonge Street, Toronto, ON, Canada").  You can get the coordinates of [the street](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=%2844.144948,-79.502926%29&addr2=%2843.64188,-79.374725%29&geocode=1&geocode=2&walking=yes) using the directions service, but you have to manually find the start and end, and possibly walking directions, maybe even add waypoints.  But you said you didn't want to do that...

Comment: It seems as though the [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) object could be of some use as it is made up of an array of lat/long points.. how on earth could I calculate those point.. hmm..

Comment: You can get a polyline that follows the road from the directions service, just not without manually entering the start and end of the road.